Load testing with functionality testing
I have a campaign with landing page with next button, opt-in page with form, scratch page with win/loose buttons, result page with next button, claim page with form and thank-you page. I want to do a load test for the entire campaign (E2E) to see how many concurrent requests it can handle.
Is it possible to do this with all functionality?
If yes, which tools do I need to use?
Here's what I have already tried:

I have tried to achieve this via JMeter. But it only works for up to around 150 requests. And then my device's RAM got full. I have 16 GB of RAM on my device.
I have also tried parallel testing in the TestNG suite with a headless Chrome browser. It works for up to 200 requests. And same, RAM got full.


Did you follow the chapter 16.7 Reducing  resource requirements from jMeter best practices document -> https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html ?

@Prome I'll surely look into it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Welcome to the community!
When I did load testing, the limitations of the device being used were a concern. Why? You likely have other applications open: code IDE, many browser windows, etc. These all use CPU and RAM, which is likely to not provide you realistic results.
The solution I used was a cloud-based tool. There are many out there (K6, Flood, Load Ninja, Blazemeter, etc). These tools allowed for more "bare-metal" conditions, which gives you a more realistic result.
The downside, they are not free. They tend to charge based on actual metered usage, which helps keep costs affordable.

Thanks for your reply! I'll ask my manager if he can provide any of these tools.

You need to use a load testing tool which supports all network protocols used by the system under test.
JMeter is a good choice because JMeter can be configured to behave like a real browser so you will generate a realistic network footprint.
With regards to "RAM go full" - by default JMeter takes maximum 1 GB of RAM, if you haven't amended this setting then you're running the system under test and JMeter on the same machine and this is not something you should be doing because you won't get valid results due to race conditions
Also you need to conduct load testing against an environment which will be used in production (or its replica) because test results cannot be extrapolated and you won't be able to guess what performance on another hardware will look like, you can only measure it.
See Risks of Testing Performance in Scaled down environments article for more details.
Don't use real browsers for load testing because they consume a lot of resources (even in headless mode), HTTP-protocol based test will give you thousands of virtual users on 16 GB of RAM while with real browsers you will not get more than 100. Moreover you won't get good results.

Ok. Now, I have setup API collection with data passing in Postman. And it works for load testing. Similarly, I have setup those APIs on JMeter as well.
